# A bag contains 4 red, 5 white and 6 black balls. 3 balls are selected simultaneously. Find the probability that one of colour is missing.

Tags: probability

I know the correct method to do this ie. making cases such as RRW, BBW, WWB etc.

But why can’t complementary method be used?
$$P=1-\frac{4\cdot 5 \cdot 6}{\binom {15}{3}}$$

Which implies the probability that at least one of the colour can repeat

Comment: Who said the complementary method can’t be used. Looks good to me.

Comment: +1 To your query.  Your analysis/answer is valid, accurate, and elegant.  It is not uncommon for a specific problem to yield to more than one line of attack.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews the answer is $\frac {301}{455}$, which doesn’t match

Comment: Oh, your answer includes the case where two colors are missing - that is, when all the balls are the same color.

Comment: So you have to subtract those cases as well, which is: $$\frac{\binom43+\binom53+\binom63}{\binom{15}3}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is correct, but you might have misinterpreted the question. The “correct” answer you gave, $\frac{301}{455},$ counts ones which are missing **exactly** one color. You answer includes when you are missing $2$ colors, that is, when you select three balls of the same color.

The correct answer under this interpretation is:

$$1-\frac{6\cdot5\cdot 4+\binom63 +\binom53+\binom43}{\binom{15}3}$$

This is still easier than the other approach.